# When is forall not for all

Tags: haskell

In the program below `test₁` will not compile but `test₂` will.  The reason seems to be because of the `forall s.` in `withModulus₁`.  It seems that the `s` is a different type for each and every call to `withModulus₁` because of the `forall s.`. Why is that the case?

```
{-# LANGUAGE 
    GADTs
  , KindSignatures
  , RankNTypes
  , TupleSections
  , ViewPatterns #-}

module Main where

import Data.Reflection

newtype Modulus :: * -> * -> * where
  Modulus :: a -> Modulus s a
  deriving (Eq, Show)

newtype M :: * -> * -> * where
  M :: a -> M s a
  deriving (Eq, Show)

add :: Integral a => Modulus s a -> M s a -> M s a -> M s a
add (Modulus m) (M a) (M b) = M (mod (a + b) m)

mul :: Integral a => Modulus s a -> M s a -> M s a -> M s a
mul (Modulus m) (M a) (M b) = M (mod (a * b) m)

unM :: M s a -> a
unM (M a) = a

withModulus₁ :: a -> (forall s. Modulus s a -> w) -> w
withModulus₁ m k = k (Modulus m)

withModulus₂ :: a -> (Modulus s a -> w) -> w
withModulus₂ m k = k (Modulus m)

test₁ = withModulus₁ 89 (\m ->
          withModulus₁ 7 (\m' ->
            let
              a = M 131
              b = M 127
            in
              unM $ add m' (mul m a a) (mul m b b)))

test₂ = withModulus₂ 89 (\m ->
          withModulus₂ 7 (\m' ->
            let
              a = M 131
              b = M 127
            in
              unM $ add m' (mul m a a) (mul m b b)))
```

Here is the error message:

```
Modulus.hs:41:29: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘s’ with ‘s1’
      ‘s’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        a type expected by the context:
          forall s. Modulus s Integer -> Integer
        at app/Modulus.hs:(35,9)-(41,52)
      ‘s1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        a type expected by the context:
          forall s1. Modulus s1 Integer -> Integer
        at app/Modulus.hs:(36,11)-(41,51)
      Expected type: M s1 Integer
        Actual type: M s Integer
    • In the second argument of ‘add’, namely ‘(mul m a a)’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘add m' (mul m a a) (mul m b b)’
      In the expression: unM $ add m' (mul m a a) (mul m b b)
    • Relevant bindings include
        m' :: Modulus s1 Integer (bound at app/Modulus.hs:36:28)
        m :: Modulus s Integer (bound at app/Modulus.hs:35:27)
   |
41 |               unM $ add m' (mul m a a) (mul m b b)))
   |                             ^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: "My understanding is that a forall is implied for all variables at the begin of all functions even if it is not declared." That's correct, but the `forall` in your example is not at the beginning of the type, it's in the middle.

Comment: What would the type for k be in withModulus₂? I understand it to be: `(forall s. Modulus s a -> w)`

Comment: It'd be `k :: Modulus s a -> w`, where the `s`, `a`, and `w` are _rigid type variables_ (technical term) bound by the (implicit) `forall` in `withModulus2`'s type. That's a different type than `k :: forall s a w. Modulus s a -> w`.

Comment: Think of it as being a bit like a variable being mentioned in the body of a lambda which comes from the closure (eg the `x` in `\f -> f x`). The caller of the lambda gets to choose the value of the lambda's parameter, but not the values of variables in the closure. In this analogy `forall` is like lambda - when `withModulus2` calls `k`, it doesn't get to choose how to instantiate `s` because it come's from `k`'s type's "closure", if you will.

Comment: Ok I can see your point with the closure but why would that make `withModulus₁` not compile?

Comment: Forgive me, I thought you said `withModulus1` was the version that did work?

Comment: Sorry I updated the question. It is `withModulus₁` that causes the compile to fail when called by `test₁`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158202/discussion-between-vanson-samuel-and-benjamin-hodgson).

Comment: Consider the following much simpler function: `foo :: a -> b -> a; foo a b = head [a,b]`. I hope it is obvious why this function will produce a type error if you try to compile it; `test1` fails to compile for the exact same reason. In the context in which a type variable is bound, the type variable cannot unify with any other types (including with other type variables) (except by pattern matching on a GADT, which isn't relevant here); this is what the compiler means by 'rigid'.

Comment: `forall s.` matches all types and can only have ⊥ in common so it's the same type, not s and s1 like GHC is reporting.

Comment: Obviously my previous comment is wrong. I just don't understand why.

Comment: [Here's another smaller example](https://gist.github.com/roboguy13/9fabafa92c8e85501034139687faffb7). The `rank2` function gets to pick the type of `a`, since the function that it gets (`f`) must work *for all* choices of `a`. This is the case for `exampleA`, but not `exampleB`. You can also add an explicit `forall` to `exampleA`'s type to maybe make this more clear how this lines up (though this would change nothing about `exampleA` or how it type checks).

Comment: @DavidYoung your gist make perfect sense to me but I don't see how it relates to my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Briefly put, a function

```
foo :: forall s . T s -> U s
```

lets its caller to choose what the type `s` is. Indeed, it works on all types `s`. By comparison,

```
bar :: (forall s . T s) -> U
```

requires that its caller provides an argument `x :: forall s. T s`, i.e. a polymorphic value that will work on all types `s`. This means that `bar` will choose what the type `s` will be.

For instance,

```
foo :: forall a. a -> [a]
foo x = [x,x,x]
```

is obvious. Instead,

```
bar :: (forall a. a->a) -> Bool
bar x = x 12 > length (x "hello")
```

is more subtle. Here, `bar` first uses `x` choosing `a ~ Int` for `x 12`, and then uses `x` again choosing `a ~ String` for `x "hello"`.

Another example:

```
bar2 :: Int -> (forall a. a->a) -> Bool
bar2 n x | n > 10    = x 12 > 5
         | otherwise = length (x "hello") > 7
```

Here `a` is chosen to be `Int` or `String` depending on `n > 10`.

Your own type

```
withModulus₁ :: a -> (forall s. Modulus s a -> w) -> w
```

states that `withModulus₁` must be allowed to choose `s` to any type it wishes. When calling this as

```
withModulus₁ arg (\m -> ...)
```

`m` will have type `Modulus s0 a` where `a` was chosen by the caller, while `s` was chosen by `withModulus₁` itself. It is required that `...` must be compatible with any choice `withModulus₁` may take.

What if we nest calls?

```
withModulus₁ arg (\m1 -> ...
   withModulus₁ arg (\m2 -> ...)
   ...
     )
```

Now, `m1 :: Modulus s0 a` as before. Further `m2 :: Modulus s1 a` where `s1` is chosen by the innermost call to `withModulus₁`.

The crucial point, here, is that there is **no** guarantee that `s0` is chosen to be the same as `s1`. Each call might make a different choice: see e.g. `bar2` above which indeed does so.

Hence, the compiler can not assume that `s0` and `s1` are equal. Hence, if we call a function that requires their equality, like `add`, we get a type error, since this would constrain the freedom of choice of `s` by the two `withModulus₁` calls.